# Ошибка которая выдается.System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Tags: wpf

До переноса в отдельный класс `СalkulaterResult()` все работало стабильно, но когда я перенес в отдельный класс, все престало работать. Ошибка выдаваемая находится там, где я пытаюсь конвертировать с плавающей запятой:

```
"parametr._value = Convert.ToDouble(parametry.textLable.text.Replace(parametry._decimalDelimiter,","),parametry._invariantNF).
```

[image: System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
parametr._value = Convert.ToDouble(parametry.textLable.text.Replace(",", "."), parametry._invariantNF);
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^
```